# Why is is not possible to call a class alias using a variable?

Tags: php, oop

I have a question concerning class importing/aliassing and using them.
Please take a look at the following code:

```
//Test class
final class Test {
    public function __construct() {
        print '- Class is called' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

use Test as T;
final class StartTest {

    public function __construct() {
        //Calling class the normal way
        print 'Calling class "Test" by normal name: ' . PHP_EOL;
        new Test();
        print PHP_EOL;

        //Calling class using variable
        print 'Calling class "Test" by normal name using variable: ' . PHP_EOL;
        $name = 'Test';
        new $name();
        print PHP_EOL;

        //Calling class using alias
        print 'Calling class "Test" by alias:' . PHP_EOL;
        new T();
        print PHP_EOL;

        //Calling class using variable and alias name
        print 'Calling class "Test" by alias using variable:' . PHP_EOL;
        $name = 'T';
        new $name();
        print PHP_EOL;
    }
}

new StartTest();
```

The following output appears when I execute this file in console:

```
Calling class "Test" by normal name:
- Class is called

Calling class "Test" by normal name using variable:
- Class is called

Calling class "Test" by alias:
- Class is called

Calling class "Test" by alias using variable:

Fatal error: Class 'T' not found in xxx\test.php on line 33
```

The first three cases are called and 'Class is called' appears on screen.
When I'm calling the class alias from a variable, FATAL error appears.

Can somebody tell my why this is happening? 
Do I really need to use the normal 'Test' name because the code will fail when I call the alias name using a variable?

Comment: [*Importing is performed at **compile-time**, and so does not affect dynamic class, function or constant names.*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-263)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import through the use operator is performed at compile-time (think of it as C pragmas). All aliases you define will have no meaning while your code is running and you must fully qualify all variable-based calls unless they're in the same namespace.

Comment: So when using long namespaces, there is no other option than calling the full namespace path + class name.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad thing. If nothing else, it will make your code easier to read and understand. Unfortunately without knowing your exact use case it's hard to suggest any design changes for this issue. Are you making an autoloader or factory? Perhaps you need an inflector or classmap?